# Threejs canvas size based on container

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I calculate canvas size based on its container? To avoid scrolling.

If I set the size based on window the canvas is too big.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well,that's not difficult.Set your render's size will work.

```
container = document.getElementById('container');
renderer.setSize($(container).width(), $(container).height());
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: Does this handle retina display, DPI scaling, etc?

Comment: good answer, I don't see the use for jQuery

Comment: @RenéK which answer are you talking about?

Answer (score 68):

Arguably the best way to resize three.js use to code it so it just accepts whatever size the canvas is as set by CSS. That way, no matter how you use the canvas your code will work, no need to change it for different situations.

First off when setting the initial aspect ratio there's no reason to set it because we're going to set it in response to the size of the canvas being different so it's just a waste of code to set it twice

```
// There's no reason to set the aspect here because we're going
// to set it every frame anyway so we'll set it to 2 since 2
// is the the aspect for the canvas default size (300w/150h = 2)
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 2, 1, 1000);
```

Then we need some code that will resize the canvas to match its display size

```
function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  // look up the size the canvas is being displayed
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;

  // adjust displayBuffer size to match
  if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    // you must pass false here or three.js sadly fights the browser
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    // update any render target sizes here
  }
}
```

Call this in your render loop before rendering

```
function animate(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds

  resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();

  mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
  mesh.rotation.y = time * 1;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

Here's 3 examples, the only difference between the 3 examples is the CSS and whether we make the canvas or three.js makes the canvas

Example 1: fullscreen, We make the canvas

```js
"use strict";

const  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector("canvas")});

// There's no reason to set the aspect here because we're going
// to set it every frame anyway so we'll set it to 2 since 2
// is the the aspect for the canvas default size (300w/150h = 2)
const  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 2, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x555555,
  specular: 0xffffff,
  shininess: 50,
  shading: THREE.SmoothShading
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

const light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xff80C0, 2, 0);
light1.position.set(200, 100, 300);
scene.add(light1);

function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width ||canvas.height !== height) {
    // you must pass false here or three.js sadly fights the browser
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    // set render target sizes here
  }
}

function animate(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds

  resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();

  mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
  mesh.rotation.y = time * 1;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"></script>
```

Example 2: fullscreen canvas, three.js makes the canvas

```js
"use strict";

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// There's no reason to set the aspect here because we're going
// to set it every frame anyway so we'll set it to 2 since 2
// is the the aspect for the canvas default size (300w/150h = 2)
const  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 2, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x555555,
  specular: 0xffffff,
  shininess: 50,
  shading: THREE.SmoothShading
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

const light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xff80C0, 2, 0);
light1.position.set(200, 100, 300);
scene.add(light1);

function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width ||canvas.height !== height) {
    // you must pass false here or three.js sadly fights the browser
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    // set render target sizes here
  }
}

function animate(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds

  resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();

  mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
  mesh.rotation.y = time * 1;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"></script>
```

Example 3: inline canvas

```js
"use strict";

const  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector(".diagram canvas")});

// There's no reason to set the aspect here because we're going
// to set it every frame anyway so we'll set it to 2 since 2
// is the the aspect for the canvas default size (300w/150h = 2)
const  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 2, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x555555,
  specular: 0xffffff,
  shininess: 50,
  shading: THREE.SmoothShading
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

const light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xff80C0, 2, 0);
light1.position.set(200, 100, 300);
scene.add(light1);

function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width ||canvas.height !== height) {
    // you must pass false here or three.js sadly fights the browser
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    // set render target sizes here
  }
}

function animate(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds

  resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();

  mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
  mesh.rotation.y = time * 1;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
body { font-size: x-large; }
.diagram { width: 150px; height: 150px; float: left; margin: 1em; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<p>
Pretend this is a diagram in a physics lesson and it's inline. Notice we didn't have to change the code to handle this case.
<span class="diagram"><canvas></canvas></span>
The same code that handles fullscreen handles this case as well. The only difference is the CSS and how we look up the canvas. Otherwise it just works. We didn't have to change the code because we cooperated with the browser instead of fighting it.
</p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"></script>
```

Example 4: 50% width canvas (like a live editor)

```js
"use strict";

const  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector("canvas")});

// There's no reason to set the aspect here because we're going
// to set it every frame anyway so we'll set it to 2 since 2
// is the the aspect for the canvas default size (300w/150h = 2)
const  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 2, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x555555,
  specular: 0xffffff,
  shininess: 50,
  shading: THREE.SmoothShading
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

const light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xff80C0, 2, 0);
light1.position.set(200, 100, 300);
scene.add(light1);

function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width ||canvas.height !== height) {
    // you must pass false here or three.js sadly fights the browser
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    // set render target sizes here
  }
}

function animate(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds

  resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();

  mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
  mesh.rotation.y = time * 1;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body { margin: 0; }
.outer {
}
.frame { 
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.frame>* {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
#editor {
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: .5em;
  background: #444;
  color: white;
}
canvas { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div id="result">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="editor">
  explaintion of example on left or the code for it would go here
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"></script>
```

notice `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` are never referenced in  the code above and yet it works for all cases.

---

Update: 2021, there is no "best" way, there are just multiple ways with various tradeoffs.

Some people seem to be concerned about perf as if checking if 2 values don't match 2 other values has any measurable performance impact in any program that needs performance

In any case there's the older answer I posted above which just checks the size of the container. People have suggested using `window.addEventListener('resize', ...)` but failed to notice that does not handle the case where the canvas changes size but the window itself does not (example 4 above).

In any case, in 2021 we can use `ResizeObserver` instead of `window.addEventListener('resize', ...)` for those that believe checking 2 variables per frame is a perf overhead. `ResizeObserver` will fire when the canvas changes size which can happen, even when the window itself doesn't change size.

```
function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  // look up the size the canvas is being displayed
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;

  // you must pass false here or three.js sadly fights the browser
  renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  // update any render target sizes here
}

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(resizeCanvasToDisplaySize);
resizeObserver.observe(canvas, {box: 'content-box'});
```

Example 1: fullscreen, We make the canvas

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r132/build/three.module.js';

const  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector("canvas")});

// There's no reason to set the aspect here because we're going
// to set it every frame anyway so we'll set it to 2 since 2
// is the the aspect for the canvas default size (300w/150h = 2)
const  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 2, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x555555,
  specular: 0xffffff,
  shininess: 50,
  shading: THREE.SmoothShading
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

const light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xff80C0, 2, 0);
light1.position.set(200, 100, 300);
scene.add(light1);

function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;

  // you must pass false here or three.js sadly fights the browser
  renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  // set render target sizes here
}

function animate(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds

  mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
  mesh.rotation.y = time * 1;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(resizeCanvasToDisplaySize);
resizeObserver.observe(renderer.domElement, {box: 'content-box'});
</script>
```

Example 4: 50% width canvas (like a live editor)

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body { margin: 0; }
.outer {
}
.frame { 
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.frame>* {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
#ui {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
#editor {
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: .5em;
  background: #444;
  color: white;
}
canvas { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div id="result">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="editor">
    <p>no window resize</p>
    <p>For example level editor might have the level
    displayed on the left and a control panel on the right.</p>
    <p>Click the buttons below. The only thing changing is CSS. The window size is not changing so using <code>window.addEventListener('resize', ...)</code> would fail</p>
    <div id="ui">
      <button type="button" data-size="25%">small</button>
      <button type="button" data-size="50%">medium</button>
      <button type="button" data-size="75%">large</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r132/build/three.module.js';

const  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector("canvas")});

// There's no reason to set the aspect here because we're going
// to set it every frame anyway so we'll set it to 2 since 2
// is the the aspect for the canvas default size (300w/150h = 2)
const  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 2, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x555555,
  specular: 0xffffff,
  shininess: 50,
  shading: THREE.SmoothShading
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

const light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xff80C0, 2, 0);
light1.position.set(200, 100, 300);
scene.add(light1);

function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;

  // you must pass false here or three.js sadly fights the browser
  renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  // set render target sizes here
}

function animate(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds

  mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
  mesh.rotation.y = time * 1;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

const editorElem = document.querySelector("#editor");
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    editorElem.style.flexBasis = elem.dataset.size;
  });
});


const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(resizeCanvasToDisplaySize);
resizeObserver.observe(renderer.domElement, {box: 'content-box'});
</script>
```

Why not use `ResizeObserver`?

1. it's not available in old browsers (like IE) if you still need to support it
2. it's not guaranteed to update as quickly.

   In other words with rAF and checking every frame, ideally your content will stay the correct size at all times since the browser is asking you to prepare your content. Conversely, `ResizeObserver` just says it will eventually give you an event. That might come 5-10 frames after your content actually needed to be resized.

On more thing is handling devicePixelRatio. That is too big a topic for this answer but you can [see more here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html)

Comment: In the second example, why do you have CSS width/height for the auto-generated canvas element? The auto canvas has inline styling for width and height so you're not overriding it.

Comment: The auto generated canvas does not have styling. Styling is only applied if you call `renderer.setSize` and not pass false at the end. That's arguably fighting against the browser. The whole point of CSS is to let CSS choose the size. Your canvas could be set to 50%, 50px, 50em, 50rem, 50vw. It could be in a flexbox, in a table, in a paragraph, in a gridbox. You should choose the size with CSS, the look up the size it is. You should not fight against the browser and force it's size from JavaScript

Comment: This IS NOT the "best way", because running `resizeCanvasToDisplaySize` on the render loop is a massive waste of perf. The best and safest would be to run it inside a `window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvasToDisplaySize)`, like this it will render only when layout changes and not every frame.

Comment: You have a very interesting definition of "massive"

Comment: should the `canvas.width !== width` be `canvas.width !== width*window.devicePixelRatio` ?

Comment: There's no "should". If you want to use devicePixelRatio go ahead and use it. Me, I almost never do. I really don't want my pages to be drawing 9x to 16x the pixels and be slow modern smartphones with dprs of 3 or 4. If you decide to use devicePixelRatio you need to ceil/floor/round it because it can be a non-integer where as canvas.width and canvas.height will always be an integer. See the link at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: This answer is very good - it helped me a lot, you keep doing you @gman

Comment: @AlecJacobson is right, but it turns out that webGL is automatically taking the device ratio into account, so it automatically renders with 4x or 9x the amount of pixels. From [three.docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setSize)

Comment: WebGL is not automatically taking the device ratio into account. Maybe three.js is, no idea, but WebGL itself is not

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best way to resize the canvas is not the accepted answer above.
Every animationframe @gman will run the function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize, doing multiple calculations.

I think that the best way is to create a window event lister 'resize' and a boolean saying wether the user resized or not. In the animation frame you can check wether the user resized. If he resized, you can resize the canvas in the animationframe.

```
let resized = false

// resize event listener
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    resized = true
})

function animate(time) {
    time *= 0.001

    if (resized) resize()

    // rotate the cube
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01

    // render the view
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    // animate
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

function resize() {
    resized = false

    // update the size
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)

    // update the camera
    const canvas = renderer.domElement
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth/canvas.clientHeight
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
}
```

Comment: The question is regarding a more general "container" not the window. How would you adjust your answer to address this?

Comment: @MikeGoodstadt One option is to look into Resize Observer (with a polyfill for older browsers) which can monitor an element for size changes. This was still unsatisfactory for me as my canvas container changed size based on animation of a drawer. Resize Observer seemed to only trigger at the start and end of resizing, so my canvas resize func only fired then, not during the container animation. Ultimately I manually animated my container with JS, together with canvas size, in sync in a basic function using requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: even this answer checks `resized` variable in each loop. you could call the `resize` function within addEventListener

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing the point here - but why do the existing suggestions involve resizing the canvas from within the animation loop?

You'd want your animation loop to do as little as possible, as it will ideally be repeated 30+ times a second, and should be optimized to run as efficiently as possible - affording the maximum fps to the slowest system running it.

I think there's no harm in calling the resize function from within the resize event listener - much like Meindert Stijfhals suggested below.

Something like this:

```
var container = renderer.domElement.parentElement;
container.addEventListener('resize', onContainerResize);

function onContainerResize() {
    var box = container.getBoundingClientRect();
    renderer.setSize(box.width, box.height);

    camera.aspect = box.width/box.height
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    // optional animate/renderloop call put here for render-on-changes
}
```

If you have some kind of render-only-on-changes set up, you can call the render function at the end of the resize function.  Otherwise the next time the render loop does fire it should just render with the new settings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's obvious to everyone from the comments above or from the API documentation, but just in case anyone else has the problem I had: Be aware that the renderer's `setSize()` method takes CSS pixels when setting the size of the canvas, not actual device pixels. That means that on high-DPI screens the actual number of pixels it creates appears to be based on `width * window.devicePixelRatio` and `height * window.devicePixelRatio`. This matters, for example, when you are trying to do what I did: capture a particular-sized GIF based on frames from three.js. I ended up doing the following:

```
camera.aspect = gifWidth / gifHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
var scale = window.devicePixelRatio;
renderer.setSize( gifWidth / scale, gifHeight / scale, true );
```

This may not be the ideal way to handle it, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the answer provided by @gman is the full-fledged answer. However, to recap the possible scenarios, one has to assume the two possibilities, which is the reason why the answers differ drastically.

The first possibility is when the container is the global(head) object: `window`, or maybe `<body>` or `<frameset>`, in which case, the most convenient method would be using `window.addEventListener('resize', onResize()) { ... }`.

The second possibility, is the one which has been originally asked: when the container of the Three.js WebGL output should be responsive. In that case, whether the container is canvas, a section or a div, the best way to handle the resizing is to target the container in DOM, and use the `renderer.setsize()` method by passing it the container's `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`, and then calling `onResize()` function in the render loop function, which its complete implementation is aforementioned by @gman. In this particular case, there is no need to use `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that allowed me to get a handle on my canvas rendering size:

First, the scene is rendered inside a `<div id="your_scene">` which has the dimensions of your choice:

```
<div class="relative h-512 w-512">
    <div id="your_scene"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
}

h-512 {
    height: 51.2rem;
}

w-512 {
    width: 51.2rem;
}

#your_scene {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then, you grab the dimensions of it:

```
this.mount = document.querySelector('#your_scene');
this.width = document.querySelector('#your_scene').offsetWidth;
this.height = document.querySelector('#your_scene').offsetHeight;
```

Then, you (in my case) set the renderer background to transparent, set pixel ratio, and then apply the size of the container to the renderer. Three.js works by appending the `your_scene` container with the renderer `<canvas>` element, so that's why the final step here is to `appendChild`:

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
this.renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);
this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
```

That should hopefully be enough to allow someone to get forensic on their scene. The part doing the most work is the `setSize` call, but you need to have the correct dimensions, and additionally, your camera must be pointed in the correct spot.

If you have your code similar to mine, but it still doesn't work, look at your camera perspective and make sure your scene objects are actually in view.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect this but this is what comes up by googling, so here we go.
What I needed was a canvas resize that always fits the screen and this can now done with CSS alone.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>minimal threejs</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #canvas-wrapper {
      background-color: grey;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #main-canvas {
      border: 5px solid red;
      max-width: calc(100vh / 3 * 4);
      width: 100%;
      image-rendering: pixelated;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.151.0/build/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="canvas-wrapper">
    <canvas id="main-canvas"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'three';

    const main_canvas = document.getElementById("main-canvas");

    const n = 4
    let cwidth = 640 / n;
    let cheight = 480 / n;
    main_canvas.setAttribute("width", cwidth + "px");
    main_canvas.setAttribute("height", cheight + "px");

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, main_canvas.clientWidth / main_canvas.clientHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
      canvas: main_canvas,
    });

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    camera.position.z = 5;

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    animate();

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```