# ThreeJS Size Canvas to fill space

Tags: css, three.js

I set up a basic example here http://jsfiddle.net/8nbpehj3/37/

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='nav'>
        <div class='button'>Button</div>
      </div>
      <div id='chart'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}
.nav {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
.chart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

There is a red nav bar at the top and I want the canvas to fill the remaining space.  Currently it goes over the available space and causes scrolling.

How can I get it to fill to size correctly?

Comment: Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046955/4045502).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the chart element is a container for the canvas. If so, you could achieve what you want with flexbox (I've added background color to highlight the areas):

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.nav {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
#chart {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}
#chart > canvas {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='nav'>
        <div class='button'>Button</div>
      </div>
      <div id='chart'>Canvas here</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I added the `display: inline-block` to the canvas element because I've found in the past that without that, this technique can cause a vertical scroll bar to appear.